# get element by foreign id in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

How I can get value by id for list in template?

I mean, I've two tables with foreign column. Lets say:

```
Author (id, foreign_id, name)
Country (id, name)
```

In a view I collect data with

```
var1 = Author.objects.filter(name='Robert')
var2 = Author.objects.filter(name='Jacky')
country = Country.objects.all()
```

and pass all of them to template.

At this moment I just can't figure out, how I can get Roberts or Jackys country by their foreign_id?

The only think, I can imagine, is to iterate through the whole country list every time in template, but it looks for me not very smart.

ps. I'm sure, there is question like this, unfortunately google even after half hour didn't give me anything.

Comment: Downvote for misleading title as this is not the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get them by their ID. You have their foreign key attribute. You haven't shown the actual model, which would have been more useful, but presuming the ForeignKey is called `country` you just do:

```
{{ jackie.country.name }}
```

Comment: That's just incredible! Thanks!